# How to return an int value from a function python

Tags: python, python-2.7, int, return, return-value

I am really new to Python and found this snippet online that I've modified, right now I have it printing x * y but I want to be able to return it as a int value so I can use it again later in the script.

I'm using Python 2.7.6.

```
def show_xy(event):
    xm, ym = event.x, event.y
    x3 = xm * ym
    print x3
root = tk.Tk()
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg = 'yellow', 
                width = 300, height = 200)
frame.bind("<Motion>", showxy)
frame.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Kind regards,
Postie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To return a value, you simply use `return` instead of `print`:

```
def showxy(event):
    xm, ym = event.x, event.y
    x3 = xm*ym
    return x3
```

#### Simplified example:

```
def print_val(a):
    print a

>>> print_val(5)
5

def return_val(a):
    return a

>>> result = return_val(8)
>>> print result
8
```

Comment: It must be a problem with my layout then as everything works but it looks like the value cant reach anywhere else in my script. Thanks for the help

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I like your sarcasm. I did it myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

By using "return" you can return it out of the function. In addition you can specifie the datatype.

For Example:

```
def myFunction(myNumber):
    myNumber = myNumber + 1
    return int(myNumber)

print myFunction(1)
```

Output:

```
2
```

You can also display the datatype which you got returned out of the function with type()

```
print type( myFunction(1) )
```

Output:

```
<type 'int'>
```